# htaccess rewrite rule config

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I would like to configure htaccess  rewrite rules but have some difficulties.

My rule is simple:

```
DOMAIN/SL --> index.php?lang=SL
DOMAIN/EN --> index.php?lang=EN
DOMAIN/IT --> index.php?lang=IT
DOMAIN/DE --> index.php?lang=DE
```

so I added in htaccess simple rule:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

and it is partial working.

Works if I type

```
  DOMAIN/SL 
  DOMAIN/IT
```

Doesn't work for

```
  DOMAIN/EN 
  DOMAIN/DE
```

For those two generates

```
  /DOMAIN/EN/?lang=en or /DOMAIN/DE/?lang=de
```

and I don't know why.

Is it DE or EN some reserved word or what?

Regards,
Igor

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work, as you wish for it to do.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{1,})/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```